# Angualar not able to get the `element` width using jquery inbuild method

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get the `element` width from `link` method using angualrjs. but i am not getting the result.

here is my code :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngResource']);

myApp.factory("server", function($resource) {

  return $resource('https://tcp.firebaseio.com/graph.json')

})

myApp.controller("main", function($scope, server) {

  $scope.test = "Hellow";

  $scope.data = server.query();

  $scope.data.$promise.then(function(result) {

    $scope.values = result;
    $scope.defaultValue = $scope.values[0].value;

    console.log($scope.defaultValue);

  })

  $scope.updateGraph = function(item) {

    $scope.defaultValue = item.value;

  }

});


var planVsActual = function($timeout) {

  return {

    replace: true,

    template: "<div id='pieGraph'></div>",

    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      $timeout(function() {

        scope.$watch("defaultValue", function(newVal, oldVal) {

          var phraseValue = [newVal, 100 - newVal];
          drawPie(phraseValue);

          function drawPie(array) {

            console.log(element.width)

            var width = element.width();

              if (!array.length) return;

              console.log(width) //i am not getting the width.


          }

        })

      }, 100)


    }

  }

}

angular.module("myApp")

.directive("planVsActual", planVsActual);
```

Comment: error as :  element[0].width is not a function

Comment: @ajmajmajma then he need to do `element[0].innnerWidth` i think

Comment: Either that or `element[0].prop('offsetWidth')`

Comment: I thought, when the angular has the in-build jquery, why i am not able to use that?

Comment: jqlite is not fully jquery

Comment: still i am not able to get : http://plnkr.co/edit/o72Q5vCM3bnvP3bc7TY1?p=preview

Comment: @ajmajmajma `prop()` is a jQuery method...you can't use that on the actual dom element

Comment: Please create a simple demo to replicate this width issue with. Lots of reasons this could be happening.

Comment: What exacrtly are you trying to get the "width" of? because the element is the actually full element as in  - <div id="pieGraph"></div>

Comment: @charlietfl prop is part of jqlite - see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: @ajmajmajma ok..jqLite or jQuery either way `element[0]` returns the dom element not the jQ object

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to `.clientWidth`

```
   var width =  element[0].clientWidth;
```

your working plunkr  - http://plnkr.co/edit/hWWAOY5SKxl700Vu8nD8?p=preview

Some documentation on clientwidth here (if you are interested) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

Answer (score -1):

finally it works for me :

`var width = element.prop('offsetWidth');`

Thanks all.

Comment: I didn't downvote but ....the whole initial problem stems from angular not having a `width()` method the same way jQuery does. jQlite has many but not all jQuery methods unless you include jQuery.js before angular.js in page and then you are using jQuery with angular.element(jQlite)

Comment: Didn't down vote, but be careful of using element instead of element[0]

Comment: one of you, familiar with `3djs` - please answer me